# How correctly refresh included PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm just a persistent beginner and I've met another obstacle in my way, so I hope that you'll help me one more time... :) I've got that HTML:

```
<div class='hold'><?php include 'image.php'; ?></div>
<div class='refresh'>Get new image</div>
```

And that PHP code:

```
<?php
 $dir = 'images/';
 $img = array();

 if(is_dir($dir)) {
   if($od = opendir($dir)) {
     while(($file = readdir($od)) !== false) {
       if(strtolower(strstr($file, '.'))==='.jpg') {
         array_push($img, $file);
       }
     }
     closedir($od);
   }
 }
 $id = uniqid();
 $smth = array_rand($img, 1);
 echo '<img src=' . $dir.$img[$smth] . '?' . $id . ' width="200px" height="50px" />';
 echo '<input type="hidden" value=' . $id . ' />';
?>
```

So now when I'm looking at my page I see in the `<div class='hold'></div>` my img from the folder images, and it's allright. BUT when I click on the `<div class='refresh'></div>` I obviously want to get another img from my folder, but I dunno how to accomplish that trick correctly.
I know that first answer will be USE AJAX, and I know that I can do something like

```
 function loadGraphic() {
   $('.hold').load('image.php');
 };
 loadGraphic();
```

and then `$('.refresh').click(loadGraphic);` but when I'm trying to do that in response from server I get TWO THINGS: `image.php` and, of course, something like `car.jpg?573c4e010c7f6`... But I very-very wanna get just ONE looking like 
`car.jpg?573c4e010c7f6`
 or 
`image.php?573c4e010c7f6` - I don't care...
So... I hope you've got my concept... maybe I'm asking for miracle - I dunno! Any, absolutely any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What is wrong with your code? I don't get what is your issue?  `image.php` is the ajax request. Then it append image to the DOM, which results in another request to the server, to load relevant image. This is expected result

Comment: You want only one request or what?

Comment: Yeah, i wanna see something like image.php?573c4e010c7f6 and that's it... Maybe it can't be done in that way...

Comment: So your server should return image in base64 format. This would avoid any extra request to get the image once img tag src attribute is set in the DOM. BUT base64 (text) is heavy, very heavy format

Answer (score 0):

Try it the following way:

JS function:

```
function loadGraphic() {
     $.get("image.php", function(data) {
        $(".hold").html(data);
    });
 };
```

Html:

```
<div class='refresh' onclick='loadGraphic()'>Get new image</div>
```

Comment: You're right. That's actually the same code behavior as the OP has. I think i didn't get his concept. Let just wait for his answer.

Comment: Bfcm, thx for the feedback, but with your advise I still get the same two 'files' in response: image.php and some picture. I dunno, like I say, maybe I'm asking for smth impossible and it can't be done - getting just one...

Comment: What do you mean with "getting image.php" ?

Comment: @impregnablefiend No, `image.php` is the request you send

Comment: A. Wolff, man I cleared all in my network window, than click on refresh btn and I see there 2 things: image.php and 16.jpg?5235235626 - I think it means that I got 2 'files' in RESPONSE... no?

Comment: @impregnablefiend `$('.hold').load('image.php');` send an ajax request to the server. The response text is added to the DOM, resulting in a new image added as HTML markup. This makes your browser requesting this image to the server. This is how it works for any image added to the DOM

Comment: A. Wolff, got it, thx for the explaining, but I still dunno how to solve my problem... I'm gonna to look through your solution with 'base64' and figure out how this can help me... anyway thank you

Comment: @impregnablefiend Instead of base64, other way would be on page load to get all available images src from server (array). Then randomize it client side (javascript). Now each time you want to get rand images, you will request server only once

Comment: From the other side, it is not the problem, that you get "two requests". It is normal way how those things work. Base64 would not be the good solution.

Comment: A. Wolff, that solution may help me only while I have few images in the folder, but then I'm gonna generate them on the my server and it obviously can't be done like that

Comment: Bfcm, thx for you too, man, I'm not even middle and dunno what way is normal and which is not yet... :)

Comment: @impregnablefiend I'm not sure what you mean by `I'm gonna generate them on the my server`. What you return from server the first time is e.g a json array containing only paths (string) to all images in specific server folder, not the images themself. Then client side, you just pick a random path from this array and set it as img src. Then it will only request this specific image. It could be an issue only if e.g some images are updated (appnded, deleted, modified) server side while your page has already been loaded. Otherwise, it won't be an issue

Comment: @A. Wolff, it's gonna be something like captcha. So I always have to apply to my server to get new img and, the important part, to get new ID of that img. You can see that part in my example, I'm creating some ID on server and put in the img AND in the hidden input. I can't do that part of my task by the client...